# Auto Header navigation no colapsa

Tags: wordpress

Estoy desarrollando un sitio en Wordpress (https://www.antoniobautista.com) en el que utilizo para el header la plantilla Auto Header Navigation de codyhoue.
https://codyhouse.co/gem/auto-hiding-navigation

Una de las opciones del menu se dirige a un anchor link en la pagina principal, todo muy bien pero en la versión mobile al seleccionar la opción que dirige al anchor link no colapsa y se queda abierto obstruyéndolo todo.

En la maqueta  aproveché el script que usa la “X” para que al seleccionar “Projects” igual colapse el menú, y funciona muy bien, pero al pasarlo al Wordpress ya no.

El script que colapsa el menu es:

```
    mainHeader.on('click', '.nav-trigger, .abreCierra', function(event){
    // open primary navigation on mobile
    event.preventDefault();
    mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
});
```

.nav-trigger es para la X y .abrecierra la nueva clase que agregué para las opciones del menú.

Al agregar esta clase del mismo modo que en el script de js en el functions.php mediante add_filter de wordpress de este modo:

```
    add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'clase_menu_invento', 10, 3 );
function clase_menu_invento ($atts, $item, $args){
    $class = 'efLinea, abreCierra'; 
    $atts['class'] = $class;
    return $atts;
}
```

Funciona, pero deshabilita la clase anterior y el link destino.
Sé que debería escribir una línea especial para este propósito. Pero no tengo idea de cómo.  Alguien pudiera ayudarme o explicarme una mejor solución?

Muchas gracias!